# Why one of these images doesn't load on Android app?

Tags: android, image, dom, cordova, amazon-s3

I have a Phonegap app which runs ok in Android and iOS, except for one reason: one of the images below don't load for nothing in the Android app, but works ok on iOS:

It works: http://mobile_server.s3.amazonaws.com/banners/assets/000/000/021/medium/serra_azul.jpg?1410372361

It wont: http://mobile_server.s3.amazonaws.com/banners/assets/000/000/017/medium/boscato_banner_app.jpg?1410372359

I checked many things like image size, especial characters, network loading (debuggin' in Chrome browser), but I think that those are not the reason.

The method im using to load the image is just a `<img src="..." />`. Im sure that there is no problem here, because the first image works perfectly.

Maybe someone can check these two images and tell me the difference that one has to another which can make the second image don't load in Android app.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using webviews to display the images?

Comment: I don't know, Im just putting the html code in a view. Im using Cordova/Phonegap framework, maybe they have a "webview" thing by default. There is something you know about this kind of problem and webviews? Thanks

Comment: FYI: Your both urls are working and loading image perfectly. So it is not S3 related issue.